# Laravel redirect to view with specific URL parameters (gives route not defined)

Tags: php, laravel, view, parameters, routes

This is my first Laravel project, i'm making a routing mistake and have been trying to solve it for days now, solution must be very simple, so i'm missing something. I attempted some similar solutions I found in other posts here, but they contained much more complex code and only made things worse for me at this point.

I have a GET route like:

```
Route::get('peppers/{id}', function ($id) {
    //return $id;      
    $pepper = DB::table('peppers')->get(); 
    return view('peppers',['id' => $id,'pepper'=>$pepper]);    

})->name('peppers');
```

And I also have a simple POST route. (for a form that I used on another page)
It inserts everything correctly into my database. The problems is in the redirect.

```
Route::post('pepperCreate', function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {

    $post = $_POST;
    $pepperType = $_POST["pepperType"];
    $pepperURL = $_POST["pepperURL"];
    $pepperAuthor = $_POST["pepperAuthor"];
    and so on... ending with:

return redirect()->route('peppers/{id}', [$id]);

})->name('pepperCreate');
```

But every time i try to redirect, it gives me an error saying:

> Route [peppers/{id}] not defined.

(My question is: Did i not just define that GET route, because it works when I click into that URL) with:

```
<a href="{{route('peppers',['id' => $topic->id])}}">{{$topic->topicTitle}}</a>
```

After days of trying different variations of this, i'm trying to figure out what i'm missing here. Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, because you need to use your route's *name*, and use an associative array for the parameters too, as in:

```
return redirect()->route('peppers', ['id' => $id]);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Jeez i feel so dumb now! I should have taken a long break to rethink it. Your solution works. Thanks MacPrawn.